# Elasticsearch in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, elasticsearch, laravel-5

I want to integrate elasticsearch in my laravel project.

I have installed using following line :

**Run command on terminal :**

```
composer require shift31/laravel-elasticsearch:~1.0
```

Then i have created elasticsearch.php in **app/config**/ and added following code.

```
<?php

use Monolog\Logger;

return array(
    'hosts' => array(
                    'your.elasticsearch.server:9200' // what should be my host ?
                    ),
    'logPath' => 'path/to/your/elasticsearch/log',
    'logLevel' => Logger::INFO
);
```

**My first question :** What should i write in place of host name

> Right now my project is running on local server with localhost:8000.

I have added `Shift31\LaravelElasticsearch\ElasticsearchServiceProvider` in **app/config/app.php** for enable the 'Es' facade.

Above all things done. **Now in which file i should add the code of elasticsearch to add, update, delete and search the records.**

I have product table I need to add product records in elasticsearch, when update product, records should be update.

I have no idea of the further process. Please guide me I have searched on google but no any example help me.

Comment: I've all the tools needed to get you started with the above. Console commands to create indexes & mappings. Classes to automatically monitor changes in models and create/update/delete elasticsearch records accordingly. Let me know if you are interested. I will setup a repo on github then.

Comment: I am using laravel 5.1 so which one is better for me. I am new in elasticsearch so please give me the easy one. I think second one is better for me to create model which automatically make the changes. But please explain me briefly that where to put that model according to laravel 5 structure.And thank you very much for your reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the following helper classes in their respective paths:

**App\Traits\ElasticSearchEventTrait.php**

```
<?php

Namespace App\Traits;

trait ElasticSearchEventTrait {
    public $esRemoveDefault = array('created_at','updated_at','deleted_at');

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::bootElasticSearchEvent();
    }

    public static function bootElasticSearchEvent()
    {
        static::created(function ($model) {
            if(isset($model->esEnabled) && $model->esEnabled === true)
            {
                $model->esCreate();
            }
        });

        static::updated(function ($model) {
            if(isset($model->esEnabled) && $model->esEnabled === true)
            {            
                $model->esUpdate();
            }
        });

        static::deleted(function ($model) {
            if(isset($model->esEnabled) && $model->esEnabled === true)
            {
                $model->esUpdate();
            }
        });
    }

    private function esCreate()
    {
        //esContext is false for polymorphic relations with no elasticsearch indexing
        if(isset($this->esMain) && $this->esMain === true && $this->esContext !== false)
        {
            \Queue::push('ElasticSearchHelper@indexTask',array('id'=>$this->esGetId(),'class'=>get_class($this),'context'=>$this->esGetContext(),'info-context'=>$this->esGetInfoContext(),'excludes'=>$this->esGetRemove()));
        }
        else
        {
            $this->esUpdate();
        }
    }

    private function esUpdate()
    {
        //esContext is false for polymorphic relations with no elasticsearch indexing
        if($this->esContext !== false)
        {
            \Queue::push('ElasticSearchHelper@updateTask',array('id'=>$this->esGetId(),'class'=>get_class($this),'context'=>$this->esGetContext(),'info-context'=>$this->esGetInfoContext(),'excludes'=>$this->esGetRemove()));
        }
    }

    /*
     * Get Id of Model
     */
    public function esGetId()
    {
        if(isset($this->esId))
        {
            return $this->esId;
        }
        else
        {
            return $this->id;
        }
    }

    public function esGetInfoContext()
    {
        if(isset($this->esInfoContext))
        {
            return $this->esInfoContext;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new \RuntimeException("esInfoContext attribute or esGetInfoContext() is not set in class '".get_class($this)."'");
        }
    }

    /*
     * Name of main context of model
     */
    public function esGetContext()
    {
        if(isset($this->esContext))
        {
            return $this->esContext;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new \RuntimeException("esContext attribute or esGetContext() method must be set in class '".get_class($this)."'");
        }
    }

    /*
     * All attributes that needs to be removed from model
     */
    public function esGetRemove()
    {
        if(isset($this->esRemove))
        {
            return array_unique(array_merge($this->esRemoveDefault,$this->esRemove));
        }
        else
        {
            return $this->esRemoveDefault;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Extends Illuminate Collection to provide additional array functions
     */
    public function newCollection(array $models = Array())
    {
        return new Core\Collection($models);
    }

    /**
     * Return a timestamp as DateTime object.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return \Carbon\Carbon
     */
    public function asEsDateTime($value)
    {
            // If this value is an integer, we will assume it is a UNIX timestamp's value
            // and format a Carbon object from this timestamp. This allows flexibility
            // when defining your date fields as they might be UNIX timestamps here.
            if (is_numeric($value))
            {
                    return \Carbon::createFromTimestamp($value);
            }

            // If the value is in simply year, month, day format, we will instantiate the
            // Carbon instances from that format. Again, this provides for simple date
            // fields on the database, while still supporting Carbonized conversion.
            elseif (preg_match('/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})$/', $value))
            {
                    return \Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $value)->startOfDay();
            }

            // Finally, we will just assume this date is in the format used by default on
            // the database connection and use that format to create the Carbon object
            // that is returned back out to the developers after we convert it here.
            elseif ( ! $value instanceof DateTime)
            {
                    $format = $this->getEsDateFormat();

                    return \Carbon::createFromFormat($format, $value);
            }

            return \Carbon::instance($value);
    }

    /**
     * Get the format for database stored dates.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    private function getEsDateFormat()
    {
            return $this->getConnection()->getQueryGrammar()->getDateFormat();
    }

    /*
     * Converts model to a suitable format for ElasticSearch
     */
    public function getEsSaveFormat()
    {
        $obj = clone $this;

        //Go through ES Accessors
        \ElasticSearchHelper::esAccessor($obj);

        $dates = $this->getDates();
        //Convert to array, then change Date to appropriate Elasticsearch format.
        //Why? Because eloquent's date accessors is playing me.
        $dataArray = $obj->attributesToArray();

        //Remove all Excludes
        foreach($this->esGetRemove() as $ex)
        {
            if(array_key_exists($ex,$dataArray))
            {
                unset($dataArray[$ex]);
            }
        }

        if(!empty($dates))
        {
            foreach($dates as $d)
            {
                if(isset($dataArray[$d]) && $dataArray[$d] !== "" )
                {
                    //Trigger Eloquent Getter which will provide a Carbon instance
                    $dataArray[$d] = $this->{$d}->toIso8601String();
                }
            }
        }

        return $dataArray;
    }
}
```

**App\Services\ElasticServiceHelper.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Description of ElasticSearchHelper: Helps with Indexing/Updating with Elastic Search Server (https://www.elastic.co)
 *
 * @author kpudaruth
 */

Namespace App\Services;

class ElasticSearchHelper {

    /*
     * Laravel Queue - Index Task
     * @param array $job
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function indexTask($job,$data)
    {
        if(\Config::get('website.elasticsearch') === true)
        {
            if(isset($data['context']))
            {
                $this->indexEs($data);
            }
            else
            {
                \Log::error('ElasticSearchHelper: No context set for the following dataset: '.json_encode($data));
            }
        }
        $job->delete();
    }

    /*
     * Laravel Queue - Update Task
     * @param array $job
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function updateTask($job,$data)
    {
        if(\Config::get('website.elasticsearch') === true)
        {
            if(isset($data['context']))
            {
                $this->updateEs($data);
            }
            else
            {
                \Log::error('ElasticSearchHelper: No context set for the following dataset: '.json_encode($data));
            }
        }
        $job->delete();
    }

    /*
     * Index Elastic Search Document
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function indexEs($data)
    {
        $params = array();
        $params['index'] = \App::environment();
        $params['type'] = $data['context'];
        $model = new $data['class'];
        $form = $model::find($data['id']);
        if($form)
        {
            $params['id'] = $form->id;
            if($form->timestamps)
            {
                $params['timestamp'] = $form->updated_at->toIso8601String();
            }
            $params['body'][$data['context']] = $this->saveFormat($form);
            \Es::index($params);
        }
    }

    /*
     * Update Elastic Search
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function updateEs($data)
    {
        $params = array();
        $params['index'] = \App::environment();
        $params['type'] = $data['context'];
        $model = new $data['class'];
        $form = $model::withTrashed()->find($data['id']);

        if(count($form))
        {
            /*
             * Main form is being updated
             */
            if($data['info-context'] === $data['context'])
            {
                $params['id'] = $data['id'];
                $params['body']['doc'][$data['info-context']] = $this->saveFormat($form);
            }
            else
            {
                //Form is child, we get parent
                $parent = $form->esGetParent();
                if(count($parent))
                {
                    //Id is always that of parent
                    $params['id'] = $parent->id;
                    //fetch all children, given that we cannot save per children basis
                    $children = $parent->{$data['info-context']}()->get();
                    if(count($children))
                    {
                        //Get data in a format that can be saved by Elastic Search
                        $params['body']['doc'][$data['info-context']] = $this->saveFormat($children);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Empty it is
                        $params['body']['doc'][$data['info-context']] = array();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    \Log::error("Parent not found for {$data['context']} - {$data['class']}, Id: {$data['id']}");
                    return false;
                }
            }

            //Check if Parent Exists
            try
            {
                $result = \Es::get([
                    'id' => $params['id'],
                    'index' => $params['index'],
                    'type' => $data['context']
                ]);
            } catch (\Exception $ex) {
                if($ex instanceof \Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\Missing404Exception || $ex instanceof \Guzzle\Http\Exception\ClientErrorResponseException)
                {
                    //if not, we set it
                    if (isset($parent) && $parent)
                    {
                        $this->indexEs([
                            'context' => $data['context'],
                            'class' => get_class($parent),
                            'id' => $parent->id,
                        ]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        \Log::error('Unexpected error in updating elasticsearch records, parent not set with message: '.$ex->getMessage());
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    \Log::error('Unexpected error in updating elasticsearch records: '.$ex->getMessage());
                    return false;
                }
            }

            \Es::update($params);
        }
    }

    /*
     * Iterate through all Es accessors of the model.
     * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model $object
     */
    public function esAccessor(&$object)
    {
        if(is_object($object))
        {
            $attributes = $object->getAttributes();
            foreach($attributes as $name => $value)
            {
                $esMutator = 'get' . studly_case($name) . 'EsAttribute';
                if (method_exists($object, $esMutator)) {
                    $object->{$name} = $object->$esMutator($object->{$name});
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw New \RuntimeException("Expected type object");
        }
    }

    /*
     * Iterates over a collection applying the getEsSaveFormat function
     * @param mixed $object
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function saveFormat($object)
    {
        if($object instanceof \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model)
        {
            return $object->getEsSaveFormat();
        }
        else
        {
            return array_map(function($value)
            {
                return $value->getEsSaveFormat();
            }, $object->all());
        }
    }
}
```

A couple of gotchas from the above helper classes:

The default ElasticSearch index is set to the name of the App's Environment

The `..task()` functions are meant for the old laravel 4.2 queue format. I've yet to port those to laravel 5.x. Same goes for the `Queue::push` commands.

**Example**

**ElasticSearch Mapping:**

```
[
    'automobile' => [
        "dynamic" => "strict",
        'properties' => [
            'automobile' => [
                'properties' => [
                    'id' => [
                        'type' => 'long',
                        'index' => 'not_analyzed'
                    ],
                    'manufacturer_name' => [
                        'type' => 'string',
                    ],
                    'manufactured_on' => [
                        'type' => 'date'
                    ]
                ]                      
            ],
            'car' => [
                'properties' => [
                    'id' => [
                        'type' => 'long',
                        'index' => 'not_analyzed'
                    ],
                    'name' => [
                        'type' => 'string',
                    ],
                    'model_id' => [
                        'type' => 'string'
                    ]
                ]                
            ],        
            "car-model" => [
                'properties' => [
                    'id' => [
                        'type' => 'long',
                        'index' => 'not_analyzed'
                    ],
                    'description' => [
                        'type' => 'string',
                    ],
                    'name' => [
                        'type' => 'string'
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Top level document is called 'automobile'. Underneath it, you have 'automobile', 'car' & 'car-model'. Consider 'car' & 'car-model' as relations to the automobile. They are known as sub documents on elasticsearch. (See: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/document.html)

**Model: App\Models\Car.php**

```
namespace App\Models;

class Car extends \Eloquent {

    use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;
    use \App\Traits\ElasticSearchEventTrait;

    protected $table = 'car';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'serie',
        'model_id',
        'automobile_id'
    ];

    protected $dates = [
        'deleted_at'
    ];

    /* Elastic Search */

    //Indexing Enabled
    public $esEnabled = true;
    //Context for Indexing - Top Level name in the mapping
    public $esContext = "automobile";
    //Info Context - Secondary level name in the mapping. 
    public $esInfoContext = "car";
    //The following fields will not be saved in elasticsearch.
    public $esRemove = ['automobile_id'];

    //Fetches parent relation of car, so that we can retrieve its id for saving in the appropriate elasticsearch record
    public function esGetParent()
    {
        return $this->automobile;
    }

    /*
     * Event Observers
     */

    public static function boot() {
        parent:: boot();

        //Attach events to model on start
        static::bootElasticSearchEvent();
    }

    /*
    * ElasticSearch Accessor
    * 
    * Sometimes you might wish to format the data before storing it in elasticsearch,
    * The accessor name is in the format of: get + attribute's name camel case + EsAttribute
    * The $val parameter will always be the value of the attribute that is being accessed.
    *
    * @param mixed $val
    */

    /*
    * Elasticsearch Accessor: Model Id
    *
    * Get the model name and save it
    *
    * @param int $model_id
    * @return string
    */

    public function getModelIdEsAttribute($model_id) {
        //Fetch model from table
        $model = \App\Models\CarModel::find($model_id);
        if($model) {
            //Return name of model if found
            return $model->name;
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }

    /*
    * Automobile Relationship: Belongs To
    */
    public function automobile()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\Automobile','automobile_id');
    }

}
```

**Example of Search Query:**

```
/**
* Get search results
* 
* @param string $search (Search string)
* 
*/
public function getAll($search)
{
    $params = array();
    $params['index'] = App::environment();
    //Declare your mapping names in the array which you wish to search on.
    $params['type'] = array('automobile');

    /*
     * Build Query String
     */

    //Exact match is favored instead of fuzzy ones
    $params['body']['query']['bool']['should'][0]['match']['name']['query'] = $search;
    $params['body']['query']['bool']['should'][0]['match']['name']['operator'] = "and";
    $params['body']['query']['bool']['should'][0]['match']['name']['boost'] = 2;
    $params['body']['query']['bool']['should'][1]['fuzzy_like_this']['like_text'] = $search;
    $params['body']['query']['bool']['should'][1]['fuzzy_like_this']['fuzziness'] = 0.5;
    $params['body']['query']['bool']['should'][1]['fuzzy_like_this']['prefix_length'] = 2;
    $params['body']['query']['bool']['minimum_should_match'] = 1;
    //Highlight matches
    $params['body']['highlight']['fields']['*'] = new \stdClass();
    $params['body']['highlight']['pre_tags'] = array('<b>');
    $params['body']['highlight']['post_tags'] = array('</b>');
    //Exclude laravel timestamps
    $params['body']['_source']['exclude'] = array( "*.created_at","*.updated_at","*.deleted_at");

    /*
     * Poll search server until we have some results
     */
    $from_offset = 0;
    $result = array();

    //Loop through all the search results
    do
    {
        try
        {
            $params['body']['from'] = $from_offset;
            $params['body']['size'] = 5;
            $queryResponse = \Es::search($params);
            //Custom function to process the result
            //Since we will receive a bunch of arrays, we need to reformat the data and display it properly.
            $result = $this->processSearchResult($queryResponse);
            $from_offset+= 5;
        }
        catch (\Exception $e)
        {
            \Log::error($e->getMessage());
            return Response::make("An error occured with the search server.",500);
        }

    }
    while (count($result) === 0  && $queryResponse['hits']['total'] > 0);

    echo json_encode($result);
}

/*
* Format search results as necessary
* @param array $queryResponse
*/ 
private function processSearchResult(array $queryResponse)
{
    $result = array();
    //Check if we have results in the array
    if($queryResponse['hits']['total'] > 0 && $queryResponse['timed_out'] === false)
    {
        //Loop through each result
        foreach($queryResponse['hits']['hits'] as $line)
        {
            //Elasticsearch will highlight the relevant sections in your query in an array. The below creates a readable format with · as  delimiter.
            $highlight = "";
            if(isset($line['highlight']))
            {
                foreach($line['highlight'] as $k=>$v)
                {
                    foreach($v as $val)
                    {
                        $highlight[] =  str_replace("_"," ",implode(" - ",explode(".",$k)))." : ".$val;
                    }
                }
                $highlight = implode(" · ",$highlight);
            }

            //Check the mapping type
            switch($line['_type'])
            {
                case "automobile":
                    $result[] = array('icon'=>'fa-automobile',
                                      'title'=> 'Automobile',
                                      'id' => $line['_id'],
                                      //name to be displayed on my search result page
                                      'value'=>$line['_source'][$line['_type']]['name']." (Code: ".$line['_id'].")",
                                      //Using a helper to generate the url. Build your own class.
                                      'url'=>\App\Helpers\URLGenerator::generate($line['_type'],$line['_id']),
                                      //And the highlights as formatted above.
                                      'highlight'=>$highlight);
                    break;
            }

        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir, I will implement this and get back to you at any query. again thank you so much.

Comment: sir one more question : I have total 3 tables which are related to product table. So one product can have multiple images, sku, variant etc. how should i manage them in elasticsearch. Should i create multiple type like product, product_image etc in elasticsearch ?

Comment: IMHO, elasticsearch should just be that, making searches relevant, instead of being a data store. Therefore, it's better to store only relevant search meta data (i.e exclude product_image). On topic, yes, you should create multiple types. In the example, you see that the mapping is called `automobile` and has a document `automobile` & its relations. Therefore you shall have one mapping called `product` with multiple sub level documents, such as `sku`, `variant` and so forth.

Comment: Hello sir, May i know what is esMain ? ($this->esMain)

Comment: `esMain` is for your top-level document model only. In my example, the `app\models\automobile` should have the `esMain` attribute to true.

Comment: now what about search query where should i write that all query ?

Comment: Added search query sample.

Comment: Thanks sir its helps

Comment: Hello mysteyyos sir can you help me in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36569635/how-to-write-global-query-in-elasticsearch

Comment: @user5876639 this package solves your problem https://github.com/fico7489/laravel-updated-related