# How to write global query in elasticsearch?

Tags: php, search, elasticsearch

I want to create top search query using elasticsearch.

I want to match `category_name`, `brand_name` and `title` from elasticsearch table. The match should be phrase and with or condition.

My query:

```
$query = [
  "bool" => [
    "must" => [
      ["match" => ["is_published" => 1]],
      [
        "multi_match" => [
          "query" => $searchKey,
          "fields" => ["category_name", "brand_name", "title"]
        ]
      ],
      [
        'nested' => [
          'path' => 'category_with_in_title.parent_cat',
          'query' => [
            'bool' => [
              'must' => [

                ['match' => [
                  'category_with_in_title.parent_cat.status' => 1,
                ]],
              ],
            ],
          ],
        ],
      ],
      [
        'nested' => [
          'path' => 'brand',
          'query' => [
            'bool' => [
              'must' => [
                'match' => [
                  'brand.approved_status' => 1,
                ],
              ],
            ],
          ],
        ],
      ],
      [
        'nested' => [
          'path' => 'default_product_low_price_with_seller.seller_detail',
          'query' => [
            'bool' => [
              'must' => [
                'match' => [
                  'default_product_low_price_with_seller.seller_detail.approve_status' => 1,
                ],
              ],
            ],
          ],
        ],

      ],
      [
        'nested' => [
          'path' => 'default_product_low_price_with_seller',
          'query' => [
            'bool' => [
              'must' => [
                'match' => [
                  'default_product_low_price_with_seller.status' => 1,
                ],
              ],
            ],
          ],
        ],
      ],
    ],

  ],
];
```

I use `multi_match` for that but how to use pharse in this query? I have to write whole word to search.

For example :

I want to search the record whose `category_name = Tops`

I want result if i write "tops" or "top" or "to". But right now I have to write "Tops" the exact word.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

You could use [match_phrase_prefix](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix), which is the same as [match_phrase](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#query-dsl-match-query-phrase), except that **it allows for prefix matches on the last term in the text**.

All that you need to do, is add `"type": "phrase_prefix"` to your `multi_match` query, like this:

```
"multi_match" => [
  "query" => $searchKey,
  "type": "phrase_prefix",
  "fields" => ["category_name", "brand_name", "title"]
]
```

Let me know if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: This approach has a limitation. Default max_expansions is 50 and increasing it might affect your query response time. Reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_query_time_search_as_you_type.html

Comment: Thanks sir, but this is not working i am not getting any records

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should use `multi_match` with [`cross_fields`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_cross_fields_queries.html) type, which will treat all fields as ONE big field and run your query on it. However, due to fuzziness being disabled on these, only the exact match will show.

**See Revelant Github Issue** https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/6866

Hence, my recommendation is to replace `multi_match` with `fuzzy_like_this` ([elasticsearch version 1.x](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-flt-query.html)) or `more_like_this` ([elasticsearch version 2.x](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/query-dsl-mlt-query.html)).

```
$query = [
  "bool" => [
    "must" => [
      ["match" => ["is_published" => 1]],
      [
        "fuzzy_like_this" => [
            "fields" => ["category_name", "brand_name", "title"],
            "like_text" => $searchKey
        ]
      ],
      ....
```

Comment: Thanks sir it works but I have to write full word to search. For example i want to get records which category_name = Tops then i have to write 'tops' or 'top' to get that records. I am not get any record if I write 'to' (to search tops).

Comment: In the `fuzzy_like_this` array, add `"fuzziness" => 3`. This will increase the likelihood of matches. It may also point to the fact that your indexes may not be analyzed. see: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/analysis-intro.html

Comment: Sir may I use query without change the structure to analyzed ?

Comment: i want to search partial search from sentence but without change the structure

Comment: You'll have to rebuild your index from ground up if you switch the mapping around.

Comment: Sir can you please help me in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37184645/conditional-query-in-elasticsearch